# How or where to practice correlation or dynamic tokens for JMeter?

Tags: regex, jmeter, correlation

I find lot of tutorials on how to use **regular expressions** to implement `correlation in JMeter`, that is, `extract dynamic tokens` and use them in the later steps, but is there any practice website where I can apply these techniques to?

Basically, I'm looking for a interactive `practice website` which uses dynamic tokens so that I can record the user interaction using JMeter and then play with Regular Expressions trying to extract and use those dynamic tokens.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @StackB00m for the edits in the question, appreciate it!

Comment: No problem Happy to Help :)

Comment: Another case of RTFM. @IshtiaqueHussain It's right there in JMeter user manual, **on the first page**  of [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html), a link to [regexplanet.com](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

Comment: Thanks Mariano, but not sure if I'm missing something or you didn't get my question. I didn't ask for a page where I can check my regular expression, I'm looking for a full-blown website which uses dynamic tokens so that I can record my interactions using JMeter and then use regular expression to extract the token and use in the subsequent steps.